# mysql row partitioning

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anybody please help me to wtite mysql query for the below mentioned sql query ?

```
SELECT Customers_Ship_To_Promotions.Customer_Ship_To + Promotions_Materials.Material_Number
,convert(VARCHAR, Promotions.Amount)
,Promotions.ID_Promotion
,row_number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY Customers_Ship_To_Promotions.Customer_Ship_To 
                     + Promotions_Materials.Material_Number 
ORDER BY Customers_Ship_To_Promotions.Customer_Ship_To 
                     + Promotions_Materials.Material_Number
        ,Promotions.Amount
        )
FROM Promotions
INNER JOIN Promotions_Materials ON 
   Promotions.ID_Promotion = Promotions_Materials.ID_Promotion
INNER JOIN Customers_Ship_To_Promotions ON 
   Promotions.ID_Promotion = Customers_Ship_To_Promotions.ID_Promotion
WHERE Type_Promotion = '4'
ORDER BY Customers_Ship_To_Promotions.Customer_Ship_To + Promotions_Materials.Material_Number
```

Comment: We will help you do the conversion, not write it for you from scratch. See this guidance on meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 
    @row_number:=CASE
    WHEN @customer_no = customer_ship_to THEN @row_number + 1
    ELSE 1
    END AS num,
    @customer_no:=customer_ship_to as customer_ship_to,
    sales_organization,
    id_promotion
FROM 
    customer_ship_to_promotions,(SELECT @customer_no:=0,@row_number:=0) as t
ORDER BY customer_ship_to;

I was stuck in row_number partitioning ,and i have tried above query for the same and i was getting the output, when i integrate the above query to the main query it is throwing error